# How do I update or push a Slack modal view on submission? (Slack API w/ Bolt)

Tags: typescript, slack, slack-api

Modal fails to update or push the new view upon modal view submission. Slack's [Bolt documentation](https://slack.dev/bolt-js/concepts#updating-pushing-views) only shows modal update or push through an interactive component. Correct functionality can be seen with the Giphy slack app.

Here's my code for the modal view I'm wanting to push:

```
app.action({'callback_id': 'gifsearchview_1'}, async ({ ack, body, context }) => {
   await ack();
   try {
     const result = await app.client.views.push({
       token: context.botToken,
       view_id: body.view.id,
       // View payload with updated blocks
       view: {
           // View identifier
           "type": "modal",
           "callback_id": 'gifsearchview_2',
               "title": {
                   "type": "plain_text",
                   "text": "Search Results",
                   "emoji": true
               },
               "submit": {
                   "type": "plain_text",
                   "text": "Submit"
               },
               "blocks": [
                   {
                       "type": "section",
                       "text": {
                           "type": "mrkdwn",
                           "text": "Updated."
                       },
                   }
               ]
         }
     });
     console.log(result);
   }
   catch (error) {
     console.error(error);
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your error?

You are missing the `trigger_id` argument in the `views.push` call. See the Slack [docs](https://api.slack.com/methods/views.push) for that API. If you use the `views.update` ([docs](https://api.slack.com/methods/views.update)) call you can pass in the previous payload's `view_id` with the new view object.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't use this method in a submit callback, instead you need to set the response_action and use the *ack* method passed in.

The documentation is *very* unclear on this, and I spent a day trying to make it work the way you describe to no avail (at least in a submit callback)

here is the general way:
https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#pushing_response

Example:

```
let newView = {
      response_action: 'push',
      view: {
       "type": "modal",
       "callback_id": 'gifsearchview_2',
           "title": {
               "type": "plain_text",
               "text": "Search Results",
               "emoji": true
           },
           "submit": {
               "type": "plain_text",
               "text": "Submit"
           },
           "blocks": [
               {
                   "type": "section",
                   "text": {
                       "type": "mrkdwn",
                       "text": "Updated."
                   },
               }
            ]
        }      
    };
    await ack(newView);
```